# Google maps Geocoding markers loading

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-geocoding-api

I have a WP with custom post type and +150 posts with complete address by using custom fields.

I'm using Google API with Geocoding to display theses posts on a map and this is display on template file.php. It works perfectly :

```
$args = array( ... );
$fiches = get_posts($args);
foreach ($fiches as $post) {
    $array_adresse = array('ADRESSE1','ADRESSE2','ADRESSE3','CODE_POSTAL','VILLE');
    [...]
    codeAddress("<?php echo addslashes($adresse_membre); ?>","<?php echo $titre; ?>","<?php echo $cat_name; ?>","<?php echo $post->guid; ?>","<?php echo $adresse_desc; ?>","<?php echo $icon_at; ?>","<?php echo $carre_color; ?>");

    function codeAddress(address,title,cat_name,guid,adress_desc,icon_at,color) {
        geocoder.geocode( { "address": address},function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: title,
                    icon: icon_at
                });
                var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, marker,
        {imagePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m1.png'});
                var myWindowOptions = {
                    content: "<h5 style=\"margin: 0 0 5px 0;font-size: 16px;\"><a href=\""+guid+"\" title=\"Voir cette fiche\" target=\"_blank\">"+title+"</a></h5><p style=\"font-size: 12px;\">Catégorie : "+cat_name+" <span style=\"display:inline-block;vertical-align: middle;background-color:"+color+";width: 10px;height: 10px;\">&nbsp;</span></p><p>"+adress_desc+"</p><a style=\"float: right;color: blue;font-size:12px;\" href=\""+guid+"\" target=\"_blank\">>> Voir la fiche</a>"
                };
                var myInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(myWindowOptions);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    myInfoWindow.open(map,marker);
                });             
            } 
            else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                   codeAddress(address,title,cat_name,guid,adress_desc,icon_at,color);
                }, 0);
            } 
            else {
                //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
<?php } ?>
}
```

But I have a problem, my markers are loaded one by one.
Someone know if an issue exist :

-to load all markers as the same time ?

-use cache to load more faster ?

-or simply load more faster ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your applications is hitting the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error often enough that it always has to wait (setTimeout) between each marker.

The first thing to check is whether you are using an API key, because you should not be hitting the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error so often if you were. For some tips on how to start using API keys, see 
https://issuetracker.google.com/116675310#comment2

If even using an API key you still the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error more often than you'd like, you can use the Geocoding API web service from a batch job to geocode the addresses once a day (to keep results fresh) and then show all markers at once using those cached results.

Comment: Hey Miguev, i didn't see your answer sorry... I confirm that I used API :
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[HERE IS MY CODE]=initialize">
 </script>